# monerod.exe socket error connect 0

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui

When I first downloaded the wallet everything was working fine, and then my computer crashed while it was running one day and it stopped working ever since, now whenever I run monerod.exe it says "initializing p2p server" and after that it just keeps saying "socket error: connect, 0" over and over again.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: That looks like a network error. I assume that computer can access the internet ? You could try removing p2pstate.bin (in ~/.bitmonero on Linux and Mac, search for it if Windows), but that's a long shot. In any case, try running with "--log-level 1" to see if there's any more info.

Comment: To add, on Windows you can find p2pstate.bin in `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but once I was researching in google y left monerod.exe running for a few minutes, and when I notice monerod.exe was connected. I hope this helps to you.